# Collection of instantiated classes?

Tags: c#, winforms

Quite new here.. and looking for a solution.

So, I'm designing a form that allows a user to enter 3 pieces of information (3 strings)

We'll call them "Thick, Material, Batch"

following a guide online, I've created a class called slab that follows this structure:

```
public class Slab
{
    public int slab { get; set; }
    public string thickness { get; set; }
    public string material { get; set; }
    public string batch { get; set; }

    public Slab(int Slab, string Thick, string Mat, string Batch)
    {
        Slab = slab;
        Thick = thickness;
        Mat = material;
        Batch = batch;
    }
}
```

I'm confused because following the online guides i've always gave a name for the new class,

Slab S = new Slab <--- I know this is slab S because I called it Slab S.

What I'm trying to do, is to allow the user to create X amount of instances of this class, say for example 7 times, so they're adding 7 slabs, so that the data within those 7 instances can be passed across the program. So, when the button is clicked it adds a slab.

I don't quite understand how I'm going to accomplish this though, my inital thought was to have a slab counter so when the button is clicked, it reads the slab counter, slab counter is currently 1, so this is the first slab being created, but how to assign it a name to pass across?
I'd like to be able to refer to that again somewhere, how? What's the best approach for this? And what about the other 6 slabs that are added?

This might be the wrong approach, as I've found out with the last approach of 30 static strings and 30 textboxes.  Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: [Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections). If after that there's something unclear, please come back and ask again.

Comment: Can you explain the functionality you are trying to achieve?

Comment: in essence the program will collect info from the user and email across in a nice html bodied format.

before, i had 30 textboxes, and 30 static variables.. but something isnt working there, and isn't good for "memory" i've been told to try and approach it a different way by using a class to contain the data.

Comment: The one who said you to use class is wise person. He suggested you the right way, use class and properties instead of 30 static variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to update your class, to use coding guideline and proper assignment

- **Coding GuideLine:** Property name should start with Upper case, it should follow PascalCasing.
- **Value assignment to Property:** Assign value passed as a parameter to a property. Right now you are assigning property value to constructor parameters.

  ```
  public class Slab
  {
       //I changed property name to distinguish between class name and property name
       public int SlabCount { get; set; } 
       public string Thickness { get; set; }
       public string Material { get; set; }
       public string Batch { get; set; }

       public Slab(int slab, string thick, string mat, string batch)
       {
           SlabCount = slab;
           Thickness = thick;
           Material = mat;
           Batch = batch;
       }
  }
  ```

Now you can use [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8), to store collections of `Slab` instances,

```
List<Slab> slabs = new List<Slab>();
slabs.Add(new Slab(1, "12", "Concrete", "1"));
slabs.Add(new Slab(2, "120", "Plaster of Paris", "2"));
...      //So on.
```

> how can i pull out all the info from slabs 1 and 3 in the list?

You can use index, to pull information of specific slab, like

```
slabMaterial = slabs[0].Material; //Output: Concrete
```

List index start with 0. `slabs[0]` will give you instance of Slab class and `.Material` will return value assigned to `Material` property

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.. fortunately i've learnt about lists already so i should be able to implement this.. one thing i struggle with with lists though, is how to map them? how can i pull out all the info from slabs 1 and 3 in the list?

when i had 30 static strings.. i could call into the HMTL body, whichever string i wanted..:

<h6> B1 + " " + M1 + " " + T1 + <h6/> + <br/>
+ B2 + " " + M2 + " " + T2 + <br/> 

i now need to somehow replace T1/M1/B1, with the entries in that list..

Comment: @JackSmith, I updated my answer, you can check it. Now if you want to check how to use this property in html then that is completely different question from this one. It would really great if you write a separate question for it

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to the accepted answer;

Using a counter as an ID can be useful, but it's not necessary in your case. Id suggest removing it.

```
    public class Slab
    {
        public string Thickness { get; set; }
        public string Material { get; set; }
        public string Batch { get; set; }

        public Slab(string thick, string mat, string batch)
        {
            Thickness = thick;
            Material = mat;
            Batch = batch;
        }
    }
```

The `List` approach as suggested by Prasad Telkikar is the way to go, but to understand how to use the items you throw in there is a bit deeper into the rabbit-hole. 
Have a read through the following code:

```
    // Create a field with slabs as an instance variable on your editting form
    private List<Slab> allSlabs = new List<Slab>();

    public void Click_ButtonSaveNewSlab()
    {
        // check if we should save it
        if (txtMaterial.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            // Our new slab
            Slab s = new Slab(txtThickness.Text, txtMaterial.Text, txtBatch.Text);

            // Add the new slab to the list
            allSlabs.Add(s);
        }
    }

    public void Click_ButtonSendHtml()
    {
        // Some HTML string to append to
        string html = "<h1>Hello Slabs</h1>";

        // Whenever we want to do something for every slab in the list use foreach
        foreach (Slab s in allSlabs)
        {
            // Add every Slab's data to the HTML
            html += $"<h6> Material: {s.Material} </h6>";
        }

        // Whenever we want to do something with every slab in the list and use it's position counter aswell use for
        for (int i = 0; i < allSlabs.Count; i++)
        {
            // Grab a Slab from the list specified by the counter i
            Slab s = allSlabs[i];

            // Add every Slab's data to the HTML
            html += $"<h6> ID: {i}  Material: {s.Material} </h6>";
        }

        // Also look into LINQ for drilling down into lists and selecting subsets
        var allBedrockSlabs = allSlabs.Where(slab => slab.Material == "Bedrock");

        foreach(Slab bedrockSlab in allBedrockSlabs)
        {
            //etc ... 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Fixation, this is perfect! your elaborations will serve as a cheat sheet from now on :-) massive thank you to all who responded!